# Class 'Modules\Media' not found in eval()'d code on line 1 in Laravel after installing laravel-modules by nWidart

Tags: class, laravel-5, module

I'm using nWidart's laravel-modules for a project. The idea is great but I don't like having the modules directory starting with a capital letter (Modules).

I decided to change the directory name in the configuration file:

```
/config/modules.php
```

I kept the namespace as Modules, but I changed path:

```
return [
    'namespace' => 'Modules',
    'paths' => [
        'modules' => base_path('modules'), // Used to be ('Modules')
    ]
];
```

I added this to the composer.json file:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Modules\\": "modules/"
    }
},
```

Now, I created a Module called Media:

```
php artisan module:make Media
```

And also created a model Media:

```
php artisan module:make-model Media media
```

My model goes like this:

```
<?php
    namespace Modules\Media\Entities;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Media extends Model{
        //
        public function categories(){
            return $this->belongsToMany( Category::class, 'category_media' );
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine, but when I go to tinker

```
php artisan tinker
```

And I try to load an Object (which exists) from the database:

```
$file = \Modules\Media\Entities::find( 1 );
```

or

```
$file = Modules\Media\Entities::find( 1 );
```

or

```
$file = modules\Media\Entities::find( 1 );
```

or

```
$file = \modules\Media\Entities::find( 1 );
```

I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Modules\Media\Entities' not found in eval()'d code on line 1
```

Any ideas on what might be causing the problem? was it the changeof the directory name? Am I missing something in the composer.json configuration? I have no idea.

Comment: Try `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading my own code, I figured out that I was not referencing the Class, but only the namespace. The correct way to call the Media class was:

```
$file = \Modules\Media\Entities\Media::find( 1 );
```

(Notice that this time I end with \Media)

And of course, the result is the expected:

```
=> Modules\Media\Entities\Media {#857
     id: 1,
     filename: "my_file.jpg",
     properties: "[]",
     mime: "image\jpg",
     extension: "jpg",
     created_at: "2017-05-21 04:37:28",
     updated_at: "2017-05-21 04:37:28",
     published: 0,
     published_at: "2017-05-20 23:37:28",
   }
```